# Rename files using substring extraction

Tags: regex, powershell, file-rename, substring

I am using a script to rename files with extension .xml. I need to remove the first 6 characters and truncate the file name to only 11 characters. So far I have script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.xml" | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name.substring(6)}
```

How am I able to also have this script remove any characters in the string that are in place 11 or after?

For example a file with name: `export12345678910112.xml` will result in `12345678910.xml`.

The length of the file name is always required to be only 11 characters excluding the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-replace` operator with a regular expression is probably the best choice:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.xml" |
  Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace '^.{6}(.{11}).*(\.xml)$', '$1$2' } -WhatIf
```

`-WhatIf` previews the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.

To demonstrate the solution with your sample filename:

```
> 'export12345678910112.xml' -replace '^.{6}(.{11}).*(\.xml)$', '$1$2'
12345678910.xml
```